# ListView with Image Adapter Locking the UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, image, android-listview

I have a listview that load images with a adapter. Every time that I scroll the screen, the listview calls the getView to refresh the listview, then the getView loads a image, doing that in my ui thread, locking my screen for a moment.

What I did was to load the images in a AsyncTask class. But the problem is that it take a little bit, and when you scroll you see the wrong image, after a while it louds the right image. I didn't want to have that problem, showing the wrong image for a moment.

I search and saw that there is no way to stop that listview automatic refresh.

What should I do to resolve that problem? Any tutorial would be helpful.

Comment: use [aquery library](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/).It will resolve your problem.

Comment: I like to use http://square.github.io/picasso/ for such stuff. You can find tutorial here: https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to resolve that problem?

Set the `ImageView` to show a placeholder image in `getView()`, while you fork the task to load the real image. Or, as others have suggested, use any number of libraries for managing all of that for you (and I echo the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) recommendation).